# Drupal 7 - Send email on error

Tags: email, drupal, triggers, action

I'm using Drupal 7 to build a website. 
For production websites you might want to switch off showing of errors
(in Administration › Configuration › Development ).
However I would like to be alerted quickly when errors are occurring so I can check out the site and fix it. So is there a way to get Drupal to send me an email when an error occurs (and limit the number of emails to max one per day or something)? I've looked at the Trigger module and under 'actions' but cant figure out how to do this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that was asked pretty long time ago already, and just have found it by accident... Anyway, there is a module for D6 which I was/am using for all D6 sites - Logging and alerts - http://drupal.org/project/logging_alerts. Looking into 'all releases' it seems there is a dev D7 version, but haven't tested it so far, and have no idea whether and how it works. Perhaps you would like to give it a try - that's what I am going to do anyway.